# Flutter Chasing(Anchor) Overlay in Scrollable Widget

Tags: flutter, overlay, customscrollview

There are W widgets and other widgets inside CustomScrollview, and I want to always follow W widgets for O overlay widgets. Also, how can I turn off and turn on the O overlay widget inside or outside of it
Please refer to the picture for a detailed explanation.
Help me, please.

It was translated from Korean to English through Papago (papago.naver.com ).

[image]

Comment: To implement a collapsible sliver app bar in Flutter, you can use the ``SliverAppBar`` widget along with a ``CustomScrollView``.

Comment: @PradipD. 
What I want has nothing to do with SliverAppBar.
Is the painting difficult to understand? The O widget must work to cover multiple Slivers who are children of CustomScrollView. It's natural to be located at the bottom of the WWidget.